# Unable to pass arguments in crosstab function postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I know that I have to pass text to crosstab function in postgres. But somehow I am unable to do it. I am not sure what am I doing wrong please Help. This is the function I am trying to create

```
    create or replace function hrms.test2(startdate date)
returns table(
employeeid int,
col1 int,
col2 INT,
col3 int,
col4 int) as
$body$
SELECT * FROM hrms.crosstab(
  $firstquery$ 
  SELECT tms.employeeid,tms.today,count(tms.employeeid) as countid 
  FROM hrms.timesheet as tms
  where dated>=|| quote_literal(startdate) ||
  and dated < ||+ quote_literal(startdate)||::timestamp + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL
  group by tms.employeeid,tms.today $firstquery$,
  $secquery$ select distinct tms.today 
  from hrms.timesheet as tms$secquery$
)as
finalresult(employeeid int,leave int,present int,absent int, holiday int)
$body$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

It runs successfully but When I run it using a date like

```
select * from hrms.test2('2017-09-01')
```

I get an error message saying

```
column startdate doesn't exist
```

I have tried a few more alternatives as well. I am not sure what am I doing wrong Please help.

Comment: can anybody please reply at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to wrap out variables with quoting `$firstquery$`, fro your code I assume you wanted smth like:

```
create or replace function hrms.test2(startdate date)
returns table(
employeeid int,
col1 int,
col2 INT,
col3 int,
col4 int) as
$body$
SELECT * FROM hrms.crosstab(
  $firstquery$ 
  SELECT tms.employeeid,tms.today,count(tms.employeeid) as countid 
  FROM hrms.timesheet as tms
  where dated>=$firstquery$|| quote_literal(startdate) ||$firstquery$
  and dated < $firstquery$||+ quote_literal(startdate)||$firstquery$::timestamp + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL
  group by tms.employeeid,tms.today $firstquery$,
  $secquery$ select distinct tms.today 
  from hrms.timesheet as tms$secquery$
)as
finalresult(employeeid int,leave int,present int,absent int, holiday int)
$body$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked after removing the + sign in the second line of quote_literal. But it really worked thanks a lot man...

Answer (score 0):

you can basically use $$ instead of $firstquery$ or $secondquery$.

i dont have rep to comment so i left a reply.